# How to wrap text around multiple images using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I be able to wrap text around multiple images using Twitter Bootstrap? not just one image, but 3, for example. I don't want two separate columns, I created an example of what I'm asking below.

[See this image for an example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uN6t.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-left">
        *your images*
    </div>
    Text
</div>
```

Make sure images are block-level